# 3 Collection Views on One View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have 3 collection views on 1 view controller.  I've tried a few of the other suggestions I've found on Stack but nothing seems to work.

All 3 Collection Views are in a separate cell of a HomeTableViewController.  I tried to create the outlet connection to the HomeTableViewController but I get the error `Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content`.

I've read many people being able to hook up their multiple collectionViews so I am a bit confused as to where I'm going wrong...

Comment: You are trying to hook up the collection views to a single outlet in the `UITableViewController` subclass?

Comment: No 3 separate outlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UICollectionView` instances cannot be hooked up to `IBOutlet` properties in a separate `UITableViewController`.

As you describe, the `UICollectionView`s are actually each children of their own parent `UITableViewCell`, and as such are not direct descendants of the `UITableViewController`. This is because the cells will be added to the `UITableView` at run time.

If you are set on creating the outlets within the `HomeTableViewController` I would suggest creating them like so:

`private weak var collectionViewA: UICollectionView?`

and overriding `cellForRow` like so:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    // cast cell as collection view parent
    collectionViewA = cell.collectionView
    return cell
}
```

As has been mentioned, the better solution would be to manage the `UICollectionView` instances from within their own `UITableViewCell` parents. Example:

```
final class CollectionViewAParentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}
extension CollectionViewAParentTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        …
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        …
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks James - so would the other option be to link them up to their own tableview cells?

Comment: Yes, that is the better solution; create a UITableViewCell subclass that contains the collection view

Comment: As Paulw11 said, that would be the better solution.

Comment: Trying it out now...within these TableViewCell parents do you set the delegate and datasource in the awakeFromNib or elsewhere?

Comment: Seemed like a ton of work for how simple my design was haha but yep I guess that was the most logical and correct way to go.  Work out all good.

Answer (score 0):

You should create outlet in the UITableViewCell. Then you can provide tags to collectionViews in each cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath Method:

```
yourCell.collectionViewOutlet.tag = indexPath.row + 1000
```

you should replace 1000 with Any Constant Integer if the tags conflict with tags of other views.

Then use these tags to differentiate all collectionviews in collectionview:cellForItemForIndexpath method:

```
if(collectionView.tag == 1000){
//Code for collection view in first row of the table
}
else if(collectionView.tag == 1001){
//Code for collection view in second row of the table
}
else if(collectionView.tag == 1002){
//Code for collection view in third row of the table
}
```

You should also keep in mind to return number of items for each collection view just like above.

Tags make the life whole lot easier , don't they?
Happy Coding (Y)

Comment: i tried tags and i think this would work if that were all if 1 tableviewcell however they are each in their own tableviewcell

Comment: @pmanning, it will work for 1 collectionview in each uitableviewcell, Have you tried this code?

Comment: thanks but i already implemented infinity james' solution.  i tried with tags however at first and what i was doing didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should create outlet in the UITableViewCell. Then you can provide tags to collectionViews in each cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath Method:

```
yourCell.collectionViewOutlet.tag = indexPath.row + 1000
```

you should replace 1000 with Any Constant Integer if the tags conflict with tags of other views.

Then use these tags to differentiate all collectionviews in collectionview:cellForItemForIndexpath method:

```
if(collectionView.tag == 1000){
//Code for collection view in first row of the table
}
else if(collectionView.tag == 1001){
//Code for collection view in second row of the table
}
else if(collectionView.tag == 1002){
//Code for collection view in third row of the table
}
```

You should also keep in mind to return number of items in collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection for each collection view just like above.

Tags make the life whole lot easier , don't they?
Happy Coding (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Create three different collection view with different collection view cell, then after you just need to add in dataSource method like below:-

```
if collectionView == collectionViewA{

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellA", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell

        return cell
    }else if collectionView == collectionViewB{

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellB", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell

        return cell
    }else if collectionView == collectionViewC{

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellC", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell

        return cell
    }else{
        return UICOllectionViewCell()
}
```

also perform same for other dataSource method.